# polkit-0.113-r0 do_configure: Function failed: do_configure

Tags: yocto, polkit

building policy kit (polkit : present in meta-openembedded [branch : pyro])using yocto and during build getting following error :

```
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: SITE files ['endian-little', 'bit-64', 'arm-common', 'arm-64', 'common-linux', 'common-glibc', 'aarch64-linux', 'common']
| DEBUG: Executing shell function autotools_preconfigure
| DEBUG: Shell function autotools_preconfigure finished
| DEBUG: Executing python function autotools_aclocals
| DEBUG: SITE files ['endian-little', 'bit-64', 'arm-common', 'arm-64', 'common-linux', 'common-glibc', 'aarch64-linux', 'common']
| DEBUG: Python function autotools_aclocals finished
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure
| cp: cannot stat '/home/user/Music/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/polkit/0.113-r0/recipe-sysroot//usr/share/aclocal/introspection.m4': No such file or directory
| WARNING: /home/user/Music/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/polkit/0.113-r0/temp/run.do_configure.4300:1 exit 1 from 'cp /home/user/Music/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/polkit/0.113-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/aclocal/introspection.m4 /home/user/Music/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/polkit/0.113-r0/polkit-0.113/m4'
| ERROR: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /home/user/Music/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/polkit/0.113-r0/temp/log.do_configure.4300)
```

**Please let me know, how can fix this issue ?**

Answer (score 0):

You see an extra slash (/) before usr ?

```
...recipe-sysroot//usr/share/aclocal...
```

This is creating problem, and say No such directory.

Fix this, Check for any prefix path you have set or it might be a typo error.

Comment: Thanks to reply but issue is not resolved after even change the // with / because as per my understanding // and / are same in path, until its have any dot(.) with it.